# EV code signing needed for own libusb-win32 driver?

Tags: windows, certificate, driver, kernel-mode

I am trying to get our libusb-win32 driver to work with different Windows OS. I already successfully installed it on 7, 8 and 10 with a selfsigned certificate that I imported into the root and trustedpublisher.

What remains is to buy an official certificate and distribute it. Since Windows 10 there is the need to use EV for kernel mode drivers but libusb already ships the .sys and .dll with valid signature.

Since theres quite a difference in pricing the question is: Do I need an EV certificate to sign the .cat or can Windows differentiate between installing with standard certificate signature in the .cat and loading the kernel module with the embedded kernel module signature?